# How can I find a more efficient solution to mapping characters to digits?

Tags: performance-tuning, functional-style

Given:

```
strings = {"send", "more", "money"};
letterMap = Flatten[Characters[strings]] // DeleteDuplicates
(*Example: {"s", "e", "n", "d", "m", "o", "r", "y"}*)
numberMap = RandomSample[Range[0, 9], 8]
(*Example: {7, 3, 6, 9, 5, 0, 4, 1}*)
```

I would like to convert these strings to integers as determined by the mapping specified by letterMap and numberMap.

For example, "send" should be equal to 7369 because s->7, e->3, n->6, d->9.

I have done this three different ways, but none of my solutions are computationally efficient enough. Can you find a more efficient method?

From Fastest to Slowest:

Using Associations and Lookup (Method 2):

```
StringToNumber2[str_String, letters_List, numbers_List] :=
(
 Clear[rules, assoc];
 rules = Thread[Rule[letters, numbers]];
 assoc = Association[rules];
 FromDigits[Lookup[assoc, #] & /@ Characters[str]]
)
```

Using Rules and ReplaceAll (can be improved a little using Thread like above) (Method 0):

```
StringToNumber0[str_String, letterMap_List, numberMap_List] :=
(
 Clear[rules];
 rules = Rule @@@ Partition[Riffle[letterMap, numberMap], 2];
 FromDigits[Characters[str]] /. rules
)
```

Using Position and Part (Method 1):

```
StringToNumber1[str_String, letterMap_List, numberMap_List] :=
(
 FromDigits[
 numberMap[[Flatten[Position[letterMap, #]]]] & /@ Characters[str] //
 Flatten]
)
```

Expected output, given inputs above:

```
{7369, 5043, 50631}
```

Most importantly, do you have any tips in improving efficiency of Mathematica code when faced with problems like this?

(*Update after receiving wonderful feedback!*)
Henrik's Compiled SparseArray method was definitely the quickest, although I'm wondering how much improvement of other methods could be realized by utilizing Compile!

Below was how I measured the performance of each method:

```
(*See how long the algorithms take to analyze 100,000 pieces of data*)
Column[{Table[StringToNumber0[strings, letters, numbers], 100000]; // 
AbsoluteTiming,
Table[StringToNumber1[strings, letters, numbers], 100000]; // 
AbsoluteTiming,
Table[StringToNumber2[strings, letters, numbers], 100000]; // 
AbsoluteTiming,
Table[StringToNumber3[strings, letters, numbers], 100000]; // 
AbsoluteTiming,
Table[StringToNumber4[strings, letters, numbers], 100000]; // 
AbsoluteTiming
}]
```

Where Method 3 = Carl's method, and Method 4 = Henrik's method.

```
{
 {{4.79445, Null}}, (*Method 0*)
 {{8.75677, Null}}, (*Method 1*)
 {{2.04422, Null}}, (*Method 2*)
 {{1.75599, Null}}, (*Method 3*)
 {{0.900393, Null}}, (*Method 4*)
}
```

Comment: Using `//AbsolutTiming` suggests `StringToNumber2` is the fastest.  But I'm curious about 2 things:  (1) Do you need to convert back - assuming this is some sort of secret decoder ring method, and (2) Does it matter if there are more than 8 (or especially more than 9) unique characters?

Comment: @JimB, 1) No converting back needed, 2) The particular problem dictates that there will be at most 10 unique characters with a numeric value ranging from 0..9.

Comment: Your test timings are about 20 times slower than mine, probably because you don't give a list of strings as the first argument of `StringToNumber3` and `StringToNumber4`.

Comment: @CarlWoll, I do give a list of strings, but only a list of 3! The problem requires that the number mapping changes, but the letter map to stay constant and the input strings to be constant and a length of 3. Given that, are there any optimizations you can think of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**

The following approach is much faster when the number of words is small and the number of mappings is large:

```
stringsToNumberMappings[words_List, letterMap_, samples_]:=Module[
    {
    len = Length @ letterMap, lrule, wvector
    },

    lrule = Thread @ Rule[letterMap, Range@len];

    wvector = Transpose @ Normal @ Table[
        SparseArray[
            Thread @ Rule[Characters[w] /. lrule, 10^Range[StringLength[w]-1, 0, -1]],
            len
        ],
        {w, words}
    ];

    samples . wvector
]
```

Comparison with previous answer:

```
words = {"send", "more", "money"};
letterMap = Flatten[Characters[words]] // DeleteDuplicates;
samples = Table[RandomSample[0 ;; 9, 8], 10^5];

r1 = stringsToNumberMappings[words, letterMap, samples]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = StringsToNumbers[words, letterMap, #]& /@ samples; //AbsoluteTiming

r1===r2
```

> {0.010555, Null}
>
> {2.2923, Null}
>
> True

**Original answer**

I assume the computational inefficiency you're encountering is performing your replacement on lots of words? In that case, you could make use of the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable) attribute of [`StringReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace):

```
StringsToNumbers[str_List, letters_List, numbers_List] := With[
    {d = Thread[letters -> ToString /@ numbers]},

    FromDigits /@ StringReplace[str, d]
]
```

Simple example:

```
words = {"send", "more", "money"};
StringsToNumbers[words, letterMap, {7, 3, 6, 9, 5, 0, 4, 1}]
```

> {7369, 5043, 50631}

Bigger example with a million words:

```
big = RandomChoice[words, 10^6];
StringsToNumbers[big, letterMap, {7, 3, 6, 9, 5, 0, 4, 1}]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.908794, Null}

Comment: Curiously enough, stringsToNumberMappings yielded worse results (5.7s for 100,000 iterations). The problem requires a stringList of three words, a letterMap, and a numberMap. The letterMap are the unique characters in the stringList (must be 10 or less), and the numberMap is a list of n numbers, were n is the number of unique characters in stringList (Length[letterMap]). This mapping is performed with the stringList and letterMap constant, with the number map varying through all permutations of n numbers. To approximate this, I used Table to perform 100,000 calculations.

Comment: @tjm167us You're comparing the wrong thing. If `permutations` is your list of 100000 permutations, then you should use `stringsToNumberMappings[words, letterMap, permutations]` and not `Table[stringsToNumberMappings[words, letterMap, p], {p, permutations}]`. I did not optimize the speed of creating `wvector` because there are only 3 words, and I only need to create `wvector` once. If you use `Table`, though, `wvector` gets created 100000 times, which is slow.

Answer (score 9):

Recently, I found out for myself that `ToCharacterCode` is very efficient in transforming strings to numbers. In particular, `ToCharacterCode` turns strings into a packed arrays which is very good for performance.

Here the preparation (stealing a bit from Carl Woll).

```
SeedRandom[123];
words = {"send", "more", "money"};
letterMap = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[Characters[strings]];
numberMap = RandomSample[Range[0, 9], 8];
big = RandomChoice[words, 10^6];
```

We create a *packed array* as lookup table via `SparseArray` and perform the actual lookup together with conversion to numbers in one go with the following compiled function

```
lookup = Compile[{{lookuptable, _Integer, 1}, {idx, _Integer, 1}},
   Sum[10^(Length[idx] - i) Compile`GetElement[lookuptable, 
      Compile`GetElement[idx, i]], {i, 1, Length[idx]}],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

StringsToNumbers2[strings_, letterMap_, numberMap_] := lookup[
  Normal[SparseArray[ToCharacterCode[letterMap] -> numberMap]],
  ToCharacterCode[strings]
  ];
```

On my machine, method is approximately twice as fast as using `StringReplace` and `FromDigits`:

```
result1 = StringsToNumbers[big, letterMap, numberMap]; // RepeatedTiming // First
result2 = StringsToNumbers2[big, letterMap, numberMap]; // RepeatedTiming // First
result1 === result2
```

> 0.810
>
> 0.40
>
> True